# Combining Multiple @Select in NGXS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngxs

I have multiple @Selects in a component like this:

```
@Select(ItemState.getMode) mode: Observable<Item>;
@Select(QuestionState.SingleQuestion) question: Observable<Question>;
@Select(ItemState.getItemNames) itemNames: Observable<any>;
@Select(ItemState.getItemStepDetails) itemStepDetails: Observable<any>;
```

Now, I want to fetch the values in my ngOnInit() for all of them and assign them to some variables which I can use in my template. I don't want to use them directly using async as I need to manipulate them.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: `forkJoin`, `combineLatest`, `zip` depending on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I'm able to use combineLatest not forkJoin though as with forkJoin the issue I'm getting is that it isn't executing the code inside subscribe().

Comment: @SunilOjha because `forkJoin` is waiting for all streams to complete, NGXS's state stream is not autocomplete stream, just use `combineLatest`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, `combineLatest` is probably the operator you are looking for.

You can still use the `async` pipe in your template if you combine those source selector Observables into another stream via `map` rather than a number of variables defined in the component. e.g.

```
this.combinedStream$ = combinelatest(mode$, question$, itemName$, itemDetails$)
.pipe(
  map(([m, q, name, detail]) => {
    // Manipulate/project the 4 results into what you need
    return { .. };
});
```

Then in your template you can use `combinedStream$ | async` to access the manipulated form, and let the `async` pipe handle the subscription.

In terms of NGXS, if this combining of a number selectors becomes common and you want to reuse that combination across multiple components then you'd want to take a look at NGXS [Joining Selectors](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#joining-selectors), or [Meta Selectors](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#meta-selectors), and use those directly in the template as usual.